# Importing owl files

Tags: api, import, ontology, owl

I have a problem with importing owl files using owl api in Java. I successfully can import 2 owl files. However, a problem occurs, when I try to import 3 or more owl files that are integrated to each other. 
E.g.

```
Base.owl -- base ontology
Electronics.owl -- electronics ontology which imports Base.owl
Telephone.owl -- telephone ontology which imports Base.owl and Electronics.owl
```

When, I just import Base.owl and run Electronics.owl, it works smoothly. The code is given below:

```
File fileBase = new File("filepath/Base.owl");
File fileElectronic = new File("filePath/Electronic.owl");
SimpleIRIMapper iriMapper =  new SimpleIRIMapper(IRI.create("url/Base.owl"),
                IRI.create(fileBase));
OWLOntologyManager manager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
manager.addIRIMapper(iriMapper);
OWLOntology ont = manager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(fileElectronic);
```

However, when I want to load Telephone.owl, I just create an additional iriMapper and add it to the manager. The additional code is shown with ** :

```
File fileBase = new File("filepath/Base.owl");
File fileElectronic = new File("filePath/Electronic.owl");
**File fileTelephone = new File("filePath/Telephone.owl");**
SimpleIRIMapper iriMapper =  new SimpleIRIMapper(IRI.create("url/Base.owl"),
                IRI.create(fileBase));
**SimpleIRIMapper iriMapper2 =  new SimpleIRIMapper(IRI.create("url/Electronic.owl"),
                IRI.create(fileElectronic));**
OWLOntologyManager manager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
manager.addIRIMapper(iriMapper);
**manager.addIRIMapper(iriMapper2);**
OWLOntology ont = manager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(**fileTelephone**);
```

The code shown above gives this error :

```
Could not load import:        
Import(url/Electronic.owl>)
Reason: Could not loaded imported ontology:       
<url/Base.owl> Cause: null
```

It would be really appreciated, if someone gives me a hand...
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Maybe this is a better forum for OWL questions : http://www.semanticoverflow.com/

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is old, but it was my first hit on google seraching for a similar problem (loading many owl-imports). And I need a lot of time to find an answer.

So for all who have the problem that the owlapi will say: "Could not loaded imported ontology": The owlapi provides a utility-class named **"AutoIRIMapper"** (described here: http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/2.x.x/utilityclasses.html and http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/javadoc/index.html).
Once created an instance of "AutoIRIMapper" can be addaded to the "OWLOntologyManager" using the following code:

`"manager.addIRIMapper(autoIRIMapper);"`

After that the OWLOntologyManager will be able to automatically load all imported OWL-Files.

I hope that will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to make a request to the manager to load an ontology declared in an imports statement, you can use the makeLoadImportRequest method, which takes an OWLImportsDeclaration as a parameter.

See whether that solves your problem.

Good luck!

Comment: Could you please give me a short example or a tutorial ?